# Преобразование php->word->jpg

Tags: php, алгоритм, ms-word

Мне необходимо часто делать много почти одинаковых заявок. 
Отправлять надо в jpg. Сейчас я делаю так: Создаю в ворде и сохраняю ( с помощью universal document converter) в виде изо и отправляю. 
Решил все это автоматизировать. 
Какой самый короткий путь к желаемому результату? 
С помощью php2word библиотеки конечно могу автоматизировать создание  doc-файла, но данная библиотека не умеет сохранять в виде картинки. 
Есть сервисы типа html2image, Но думаю это костыли. 
Подскажите пожалуйста кто-нибудь оптимальное решение.

Comment: Отправка заявки в JPG само по себе уже костыли и извращение. Как выглядит заявка? Кусок текста на А4?

Comment: Да, с отканированной подписью и печатью. Необязательно в jpg, можно и в tiff

Comment: А чем вам PDF не угодил?

Comment: А php2word позволяет сохранять в pdf?

Comment: Вот, юзайте:

1. http://www.tcpdf.org/
2. https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf
3. https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf